# jQuery reveal and wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Having a problem with a jQuery pop up modal (top right beside my name). It works grand before word pressing the site (http://edwardmanson.com/test/) but after linking it all together and putting it in wordpress it stops working (http://edwardmanson.com). Any help would be much appreciated to get it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be a jQuery version conflict.  At the top of your live page, you have included jQuery 1.7.1.  At the *bottom* of the page, you have included jQuery 1.4.  I did some experimentation, and found that it works if you remove the inclusion of jQuery 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress's packaged jQuery defaults to [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, so `$` won't work out of the box, use `jQuery` like `jQuery('document')`, or wrap your code like

```
(function($) { 
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
})(jQuery);
```

or in your document ready like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

and as Ethan Brown said, you're loading jQuery twice, at the very least it's wasting bandwidth...